# Can a self-inverse function introduce bias?

Tags: functions

I have a self-inverse function $f(x)$, with the domain $\{x: 0 \le x \lt n\}$ (for some arbitrary $n$) such that $x$ is a nonnegative integer. I'm looking for a proof that $f(x)$ cannot introduce any kind of statistical bias.

---

- Since $f$ is a self inverse, every output must be within the domain. Otherwise, $f$ could produce an output it cannot use as an input, therefore not being a self-inverse.
- Since $f$ is a self inverse, any introduction of bias would mean it's more likely to produce a certain output. Since $f$ is a self inverse, this would be impossible.

  - $f$ cannot produce any output more than once, since the inverse would no longer be a function (for each output of a function, there must be exactly 1 corresponding input)
  - Since $f$ is its own inverse, this would make $f$ not a function

---

I think I have a good basis for my proof, but I'm unable to articulate why these properties mean there cannot be bias introduced by $f$.

One idea I have is I can model $f$ as a permutation of the set of integers $\{x: 0 \le x \lt n\}$, then elaborate on how a permutation of a set cannot introduce bias (I'm thinking this is the most likely to come out as a clear explanation).

In my case, $f(x)$ operates within a finite range (integers from $1$ up to $n$). One answer mentions $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ being a self-inverse that changes the average for $x$ between $0$ and $1$, but it relies on the fact that one can choose infinite possible $x$.

I purposely fail to define what "bias" means; because within the scope of this question, I refer to *any possible* bias. I understand that this lack of specific definition makes this question weird (which is why I was unable to develop a clear answer myself, and therefore why I needed to ask this question).

Comment: What do you mean by $f$ "introducing bias"?

Comment: I mean any statistical tendencies in the output. Specifically, as represented as a set of bits, the distribution of $0$s and $1$s, but any more generally statistical bias is within the scope of what I consider bias

Comment: Your question is quite unclear as it stands. One would need to know what you're doing with this function.

Comment: Well, you can't possibly prove anything without a precise definition of what you're proving.  So I would suggest you figure that out first.

Comment: @EricWofsey Apparently you can.  (See my answer below.)  Though I agree, this is an exception; the question itself is of a rather low quality...

Comment: The question makes no specific definition of what "bias" means because there is no precise definition in this context. $f$ must avoid introducing any statistical bias, regardless of what kind of bias is searched for, since $f$ is used as part of a cryptosystem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could argue that $f$ simply "renames" the values.  Therefore, it cannot introduce any bias because it is the $identity$ function -- simply it gives the values new names.  E.g. the name of "1" is now "5", the name of "2" is "1", etc.

Note: This approach works regardless of what "introducing statistical bias" means -- which in my field (cryptography) is a rather long definition.

Comment: By your example, it would seem that any automorphism  is the identity function as it renames each element in its domain by $x\to f(x)$?

Answer (score 0):

If by "introducing bias" you mean "changing the average from what it was originally", then such a function could definitely "introduce bias". By [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality), we would expect the average to be biased upwards if $y = f(x)$ has a concave downwards graph, and biased downwards if $y = f(x)$ has a concave upwards graph.

Simple example: Let $X$ be uniformly distributed on $\left[ 0, 1 \right]$, so that $E[X] = 0.5$. $f(x) = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$ is self-inverse on this domain, but $E[f(X)] = \pi / 4$, so applying this self-inverse function has biased the average upwards.

Comment: This example, however, relies on the set in question being a non-discrete set.  The OP asks about a discrete set.